# Use jQuery. data() with select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-data

I have the code below to change dynamically an image. It work as it should but I have some questions:

**1 - Why**

```
$('#image').attr('data-picture-name', $this.val());
```

work but

```
$('#image').data('picture-name', $this.val());
```

don't work ? and is there any way to use data() instead of attr() ?

**2 - Retrieve data from the data-parameters value in the selected option**

How can I get the value from data-parameters in the selected option ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img data-picture-name="popol" src="" id="image" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid red;" />
    <select name="meteo-list-cities" id="meteo-list-cities" class="triggered" data-trigger-change-call="meteo-country-change-trigger">
        <option data-parameters="1" value="assets/images/newyork.jpg">New York</option>
        <option data-parameters="2" value="assets/images/paris.jpg">Paris</option>
        <option data-parameters="3" value="assets/images/london.jpg">London</option>
    </select>

    <script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#meteo-list-cities').on('change', function () {
                var $this= $(this);
                $('#image').attr('data-picture-name', $this.val());
                $('#image').attr('src', $this.val());
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.data()` method doesn't change the `data-*` attributes, it modifies the properties behind the scene, probably that's why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: May be :) But if i display the data-picture-name value, with data() I'll always have popol, but with attr() i have the correct image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use data to store extra information. You can get and set that info, which could be a simple string or a complex object using jquery data. Unlike setting the attribute, this data object is hidden from source view.

SET

```
$('#image').data('cityImgPath', $this.val() );

$('#image').data('complexColorObj', { imgPath: "http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2012/04/24/article-2134408-12BFD96D000005DC-434_964x788.jpg", color: "blue", mood: "depressed" } );
```

GET

```
var newImagePath = $('#image').data('cityImgPath');

var myMoodBeforeCoffee = $('#image').data('complexColorObj').mood;
```

Once you have that variable, then you can apply it to your div

```
$('#image').attr('src', newImagePath );
```

[api for jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Comment: Interesting . With the answer of Blacksheep I understood I must use attr() instead of data() for displayed attributes but if I want to hide some datas I could use data().